# addEventListener isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure why this isn't working... I'll post what doesn't work first, then I'll post what does work underneath it:

This didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById('theButton').addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="<label for=\"Name\">What is your name?</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"Name\"/>";
document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="http://www.w3schools.com";
document.getElementById('myAnchor').target="_blank";
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Change link">

</body>
</html>
```

This did work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeLink()
{
document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="<label for=\"Name\">What is your name?</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"Name\"/>";
document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="http://www.w3schools.com";
document.getElementById('myAnchor').target="_blank";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
<input type="button" onclick="changeLink()" value="Change link">

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this with my little adjustment to the innerHTML at:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_elmnt_innerhtml

Comment: Just move your script down below the `<input ...>` but above the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Don't use [W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com/), The [*Mozilla Developer Network* (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a much better resource.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is script is load before myAncor object. Therefore you cannot get it with document.getElementById function. You should call this function after load page DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

If you append the script in head, before the html, the html doesn't exists yet when you try to add the event listener. So you need to wrap it in a onload:

```
window.onload=function(){
 //your code
}
```